# How to implement Lucene.Net.Analysis.Phonetic in lucene.net?

Tags: c#, lucene.net

From apache documentation it's clear that they have a phonetic search feature in Lucene.net. But I am unable to find any guideline or example that describes how to implement this in searching. How to do it in c#, any sample/example will really help me.

Comment: Their GitHub might haxe examples? Did u look there

Comment: Went through their github repo but really couldn't find anything. Apache has some amazing tools with the worst documentation.

Comment: The [analyzer documentation](https://lucenenet.apache.org/docs/4.8.0-beta00015/api/core/Lucene.Net.Analysis.html) explains in some detail what a `TokenFilter` is and how to use one to build a custom analyzer. The `Lucene.Net.Phonetic` components are all implemented as `TokenFilter`s.